# __invoke behavior lost on object reference

Tags: php, oop, invoke

Recently I came across with the following issue. This is a simple example where the issue occurs.

```
class a{
    public function __invoke($classname){
        return new $classname($this);
    }
}
class b{
    private $obj;
    public function __construct($obj){
        $this->obj = $obj;
    }
    public function getC(){
        return $this->obj('c');
    }
}
class c{}

$a = new a;
$a('b')->getC();
```

When i execute this code, I get the following error

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method b::obj()

It seems the behavior of __invoke is lost on the object reference on this line

```
return $this->obj('c');
```

Its actually not that big problem for me because I can do it this way as well

```
return $this->obj->__invoke('c');
```

..but i would really like to know why __invoke does not work as expected here. Can anyone explain me this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that it's because functions and objects in PHP are still not treated quite equally (even though recent versions of PHP have tried to fix this). I suspect there's a language limitation that doesn't allow for the `obj` in `$this->obj()` to be treated as an object (since that syntax would normally refer to a method), and so it instead inspects only the methods exposed by the class.

I've not tested it, but this might work:

```
$obj = $this->obj;
return $obj('c');
```

Of course, ideally, `$this->obj` should be accessible as an object whether it's a field of the class or a method defined by the class. This way, it wouldn't matter that there's an ambiguity in the syntax since there's no need for a distinction in the first place, but PHP doesn't work like this!